# How to pass a Query String in JSP

Tags: jsp, printing, label, parameter-passing, query-string

I have Created some String Variables called Name,Address,age in a page called index.jsp page.
now i want to pass those String variables to another jsp page called Display.

and in Display.jsp page, i want to print Name(which we took as above) in a label !

Please help me guys!
im a beginner

Comment: read some tutorials and try, then post if you face any problems. start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14014/basics.htm#i1009026) **Hints:** you can pass like: `http://hostname.com?Name=a&Address=b&age=c` then you can retrieve in _Display.jsp_ `<%= request.getParameter("Name") %>` ..

Answer (score 2):

here

```
<a href="Display.jsp?name=<%=Name%>&address=<%=Addrress%>&age=<%=Age%>">
<input type="button" value="Display"  id="display" name="display">
</a>
```

then you can get these values in Display.jsp..

```
String Name=request.getParameter("name");
String Address=request.getParameter("address");
String Age=request.getParameter("age");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like this:

```
<sql:query var="rs" dataSource="${db}">select * from customers where name = '<%=Name %>' and address = '<%=Address %>' and age = <%=Age%> </sql:query>
```

For numerical fields don't use 'single quotes' with `<%=<Your Variables%>`.